# how to use np.where, where column data is not replaced

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to use np.where to create new column based on ifs.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

>>>d
Match    X     Y  end_X  end_Y   xG  player  team    action  half
0   Motherwell  31.1 5.5  23.9  15.3    0   6. P.McGinn Hibernian   Passes accurate 1st half
1   Motherwell  33.1 12.7 34.6  2.9     0   5. R.Porteous   Hibernian   Passes accurate 1st half
2   Motherwell  35.0 4.7  25.5  15.7    0   6. P.McGinn Hibernian   Passes accurate 1st half
3   Motherwell  24.2 16.5 8.3   30.4    0   5. R.Porteous   Hibernian   Passes accurate 1st half
4   Motherwell  4.2 58.0  60.8  64.8    0   16. L.Stevenson Hibernian   Passes accurate 1st half
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1358    Rijeka (h)  86.7    60.9    87.9    66.3    0   7. K.Magennis   Hibernian   Passes accurate 2nd half
1359    Rijeka (h)  87.9    66.3    87.0    59.4    0   16. L.Stevenson Hibernian   Passes accurate 2nd half
1360    Rijeka (h)  85.1    52.3    97.0    31.9    0   7. K.Magennis   Hibernian   Passes accurate 2nd half
1361    Rijeka (h)  67.4    41.1    73.2    19.0    0   22. J.Doyle Hibernian   Passes accurate 2nd half
1362    Rijeka (h)  73.2    19.0    62.5    1.4 0   10. M.Boyle Hibernian   Passes accurate 2nd half

xo = 6.5625
yo = 5.66

dfc1 = {1:[0.001,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.001]}
dfc1 = pd.DataFrame(dfc1)
dfc2 = {1:[0.002,0.002,0.003,0.003,0.003,0.004,0.004,0.003,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.001]}
dfc2 = pd.DataFrame(dfc2)
dfc3 = {1:[0.002,0.003,0.003,0.003,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.005,0.003,0.003,0.002]}
dfc3 = pd.DataFrame(dfc3)
dfc4 = {1:[0.003,0.003,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.003,0.003]}
dfc4 = pd.DataFrame(dfc4)
dfc5 = {1:[0.003,0.004,0.004,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.004,0.004]}
dfc5 = pd.DataFrame(dfc5)

d['Start'] = np.where((d['X'] < xo) & (d['Y'] < yo), dfc1.loc[0].values,
(np.where((d['X'] <xo)  & (d['Y'] > yo) & (d['Y'] < yo*2),dfc1.loc[1].values,
(np.where((d['X'] <xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*2) & (d['Y'] < yo*3),dfc1.loc[2].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*3) & (d['Y'] < yo*4),dfc1.loc[3].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*4) & (d['Y'] > yo*5),dfc1.loc[4].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*5) & (d['Y'] > yo*6), dfc1.loc[5].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*6) & (d['Y'] > yo*7),dfc1.loc[6].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*7) & (d['Y'] > yo*8),dfc1.loc[7].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*8) & (d['Y'] > yo*9),dfc1.loc[8].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*9) & (d['Y'] > yo*10),dfc1.loc[9].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*10) & (d['Y'] > yo*11),dfc1.loc[10].values,
(np.where((d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*11) & (d['Y'] > yo*12),dfc1.loc[11].values,
(np.where((d['X'] > xo) & (d['X'] < xo*2) & (d['Y'] < yo),dfc2.loc[0].values,
```

The issue I face with np.where -  is that I get an error that states I've used too many parentheses, but the code requires me to use about 190+
But if I was to split it up into multiple `np.where` then it would overwrite the data already in that column.
Is there anyway around me using multiple instances of `np.where` without overwriting the data?

Comment: Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661586/how-to-reduce-a-function-that-is-increasing-constantly-in-python/68793348#68793348). It is somewhat similar in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas masking function

```
# Applying the condition
df['new'].mask(df['X'] < x0, 0, inplace=True)
```

And if you need to create the column, you firstly could use a np.where()

```
# Applying the condition
df['new'] = np.where(df['X'] != x0, 23, None)
df['new'].mask(df['X'] < x0, 0, inplace=True)
```